# Complex JSON data structure best practice

Tags: json, api, rest, data-structures

I would like to know which of JSON data structure is simpler and more convenient for REST API consumers.

Suppose, we have POST method, which require complex data structure in request body. Which of structures is more preferable? They are equavalent.

1.

```
{
    SearchPropertiesFilter: [
        { key: 'key1', values: ['value1', 'value2'] },
        { key: 'key1', values: ['value3', 'value4'] },
        { key: 'key2', values: ['value5'] }
    ],
    ResultPropertiesCount: [
        { key: 'key1', count: 100},
        { key: 'key2', count: 500},
    ]
}
```

2.

```
{
    SearchPropertiesFilter: {
        'key1': [['value1', 'value2'], ['value3', 'value4']],
        'key2': [['value5']]
    }
    ResultPropertiesCount: {
        'key1': 100,
        'key2': 500
    }
}
```

On one hand, first example may simpler for consumer.
On other hand, second example is shorter and don't contain property names.

Comment: You can use any representation format you want, there is no REST constraint about that. If you want to search then I recommend to use GET instead of POST. POST is for creating resources, GET is for getting a representation of them.

Comment: Yes, I know, technically, I can use any. But which better and simpler for consumers?

Comment: If you can't come up with any benefits for the first one, then pick the second?

Answer (score 3):

By [**definition**](http://www.json.org/)

> JSON is built on two structures:
>
> A collection of name/value pairs. In various languages, this is
>   realized as an object, record, struct, dictionary, hash table, keyed
>   list, or associative array. An ordered list of values. In most
>   languages, this is realized as an array, vector, list, or sequence.

So JSON is already a key-value pair system, what’s the point of the redundancy of having pairs with a type key and a value key when `key:val` will do?

go for version 2